# wordpress help - undefined function

Tags: wordpress

Good morning, I have my website mounted with a template in word press, I was working quietly and suddenly this error:

```sh
error 500

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function nocache_headers() in /home/u248341626/domains/nodomed.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /home/u248341626/domains/nodomed.com/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php(13): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/u248341626/domains/nodomed.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php on line 36**
```

Someone can help me, I have no programming or development knowledge and I don't want to start the whole page over.

Comment: Please note that this isn't the place to ask for remote assistance. Any comments or answers need to be included here.  As such, I've removed that part from your question. That said: as written, this really isn't on topic here. Maybe consider posting to wordpress.stackexchange.com, as that q&a site is specific to WordPress-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's Seem Directory And Permission Error
Try To Set

All directories must have 755 rules, for all files set 644 rules
Also, try to set read-only attribute for wp-load.php

Comment: It worked for me, but when I update the WordPress it returns to the error and the file is already modified in read-only

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your WordPress then check your website. If you get the same error after some time, then Go to Cpanel > File Manager > Search for the wp-load.php file. change the permission to 644. Make the file permission read-only

Comment: It worked for me, but when I update the WordPress it returns to the error and the file is already modified in read-only